# SQL Server Audit - Where's SENSITIVE_BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP?

Tags: sql-server, audit

The documentation lists several "SENSITIVE" groups (e.g., SENSITIVE_BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP) that are new for SQL 2019.  I both want and need it.  However, I can't find these to select.  If I try to use the SENSITIVE groups in script, I get a syntax error.  I'm at 15.0.4123 (CU 10).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions?view=sql-server-ver15

Do I need to add a feature or install a feature pack to have access to this audit group?

Comment: Do you have `sa` rights?

Comment: Yes, member of sysadmin.  The audit is working without this group.  I can't see SENSITIVE  groups in the GUI drop down.  Can't use them in script.  Wondering if others have seen it.  I hope it's just me...this time.